# Can implicit & explicit bean declarations work together

Tags: xml, jsf-2, managed-bean

Is there possibility to use both implicit & explicit bean declaration together in the same App, I mean @ManageBean and explicit managed bean inside faces-config.xml, I know It's rarely used, But I felt trying it out, curiosity's killing me, ended up getting null values, any light shed on this quite appreciated .

Update: sorry for not backing up my problem with the code snippets .

starting off with managedbean :

```
package pck;
import javax.faces.bean.*;
import java.io.*;
@ManagedBean   
public class SimpleController implements Serializable{
private String message="";

public String getMessage() {
return(message);
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public String doNavigation() {
 if (message.trim().length() < 2) {
  return("too-short");
 } else {
  String[] results =  { "page1", "page2", "page3" };
  return(RandomUtils.randomElement(results));
 }
 }
 }
```

faces-config.xml stuff :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
 version="2.0">

 <managed-bean>
<managed-bean-name>messageHandler</managed-bean-name>
<managed-bean-class>
  pck.SimpleController
</managed-bean-class>
<managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>
<from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
<!--     <navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>too-short</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/error-message.xhtml</to-view-id>
 </navigation-case> -->
<navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>page1</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/result-page-1.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
<navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>page2</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/result-page-2.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
<navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>page3</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/result-page-3.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
 <navigation-rule>
<from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
 <from-outcome>too-short</from-outcome>    
  <to-view-id>/error-message.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
</faces-config>
```

welcome facelet :

```
<h:form>
 <!-- If I used implicit bean declaration, It heads to error-page.xhtml, however I insert 
  more-than-letter word -->       
 <h:inputText value="#{messageHandler.message}"/> 
<br/>
<!-- If I used implicit bean declaration along with condition above, It heads successfully to
     a random result page, But with a null expression value -->
 <h:commandButton value="Show Results" action="#{messageHandler.doNavigation}"/>
</h:form>
```

result facelet :

A page with just an expression value, but this time using explicit bean declaration

```
  <h2>Your message: "#{messageHandler.message}"</h2>
```

It works perfectly If either implicit or explicit bean declaration is used .

Comment: Surely that should just work. Your problem is caused elsewhere. It's hard to answer as long as you don't describe the concrete problem in detail.

Comment: Yes, what is the problem? `#{messageHandler.doNavigation()}` not working?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare the managed bean scope along with the `@ManagedBean`. It will then default to `@NoneScoped` which effectively means that a brand new instance is created on every single EL expression evaluation of `#{messageHandler}`. The input field will get its own instance. The command button will get its own instance. The "Your message" line in the result page will get its own instance. You effectively end up with three completely distinct instances instead of only one.

Given that you placed the bean in the session scope by XML, you should do the same using the `@SessionScoped` annotation. This way the one and same bean instance will be used throughout the entire HTTP session.

```
@ManagedBean(name="messageHandler")
@SessionScoped
```

*(note that I specified the managed bean name as well as the class name is not `MessageHandler`, but `SimpleController`; you forgot that in the question, which is perhaps just carelessness)*

Note that the XML declaration has always precedence over the annotation declaration. So if both are present, the XML declaration would always override the annotation declaration.

Comment: Hey BalusC, I thought providing scope at face-config.xml would define scope for the bean, due to my thinking I deleted scope annotation at the bean, my thinking turned out to be wrong, I did not know all info you said above, second If I gave the bean an exact name as explicit bean name,@ManagedBean(name"messagehandler"), I will have no chance to use simpleController along with explicit bean name, thanks